# How to send outlook mail as rest api

Tags: c#, .net, rest, outlook

I am trying to send an outlook mail using postman. Is there any rest service from Microsoft to give that feasibility?

I have gone through a few links and found the below API but looking for an authentication token. Can someone please check and point me to the link?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

Comment: I haven't found the relevant link/ doc

Comment: You can use [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to experiment and it will automatically get your token. Enabling getting a token in your application [depends on a few things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts)